# python pygame load image to Initialize screen very slowly

Tags: python, pygame

I write a script to implementate the continuous rains,the function is totally correct.

Only one issue is when i run the script is it really slow to initialize screen, it almost takes 6-8 seconds then i can see the image on the screen.

i search some reasons for why cause this issue such as use`convert_alpha()` to load the image, but nothing changed, it is still very slowly

So what caused this issue???

here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame as p
from random import randint

#13-4

class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),p.RESIZABLE,0)
        self.speed = 1  #rain speed
        p.display.set_caption("EXE 13-4")

class Rain(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=p.image.load("../image/rain.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=p.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))  
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)/2         
        self.y=float(self.rect.y)              # store the rain rect in temp y

    def create(self,setting,rains):
        spacex=setting.w-2*self.rect.x         #calculate the space to put the rain
        numbers=int(spacex/(2*self.rect.x))    #calculate the numbera of every column
        rows=int(setting.h/(self.rect.height)) #calculate the rows
        for row in range(rows):
            for number in range(numbers):      #store the whole rain into Group rains
                rain=Rain()
                rain.number=number
                rain.row=row
                rain.rect.x =rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*number
                rain.y = rain.rect.y+2*rain.rect.height*row
                rain.rect.y =rain.y
                rains.add(rain)
    def check_edge(setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():           #if any rain reach the bottom of screen restart them to the top
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:
                rain.y=0
                rain.rect.y=rain.y
   def update(self,setting):
        self.y += setting.speed
        self.rect.y= self.y
    def blit(setting,rains):
        rains.update(setting)
        rains.draw(setting.screen)


def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    rain=Rain()
    rains=p.sprite.Group()
    rain.create(setting,rains)
    while True:
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
        setting.screen.fill((0,0,255))
        Rain.check_edge(setting,rains)
        Rain.blit(setting,rains)
        p.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually do is to load the same image again and again for each instance of `Rain`.

Load the image once and use the same image for all the raindrops. e.g. use a [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) for the raindrop image (`Rain.raindrop_pic`). Furthermore, avoid to do [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) and [`transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) multiple times:

```py
class Rain(p.sprite.Sprite):

    raindrop_pic = p.transform.smoothscale(
        p.image.load("../image/rain.jpg").convert_alpha(), (100,100)) 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = Rain.raindrop_pic 

        # [...]
```